# Travel Spain-Poland

Tags: schengen, spain, covid-19, poland

I had a scheduled flight on Sept. 18 to Wroclaw to start my PhD program.

Poland banned direct flights from Spain (https://www.gov.pl/web/koronawirus/informacje-dla-podrozujacych), so the only option left is doing transit on Franfurt (Lufthansa flight).

In the airport webpage (https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/news/information-on-the-coronavirus.html) it stated that quarantine requirement does not apply to travellers in transit through Germany. But in the Bundespolizei page there is some points I do not understand very well (https://www.bundespolizei.de/Web/DE/04Aktuelles/01Meldungen/2020/03/200317_faq.html?nn=5931604#doc13824392bodyText9). The point 3. is the problem, as far as I understand, Traveling within Schengen zone (to Poland) does not require an exemption from travel restrictions, or that is what I understand reading the webpage of the Polish government linked above.

Does this means I should have no problems (or will not need additional confirmations) with my flights?

Sorry if the question seems too trivial but I want to be as sure as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The relevent information to answer your question is: do you have a polish d-visa (permission to stay in Poland > 90 days)? If **yes**, you fullfill the condition of the polish site (foreigners with the right of permanent or temporary stay in the territory of Poland) and point 3 of the german site (Entry into the destination country (or, if applicable, another transit country) is permitted for third-country nationals).

Comment: @MarkJohnson I don't have a d-visa, because being an EU citizen I don't need it (as far as I know). However, I have a document issued by the University of Wroclaw that shows I am a PhD student in Poland, so I would fullfill the requirements of the polish government with that (9th point in the list). Thank you very much

Comment: That and as a EU Citizen (point 11 of the list).

Comment: I believe a good option could be to check with the Polish consulate in the city you travel to in Spain and most probably they should be able to help

Comment: @LuisL Or rather the Polish border guard headquarters

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.